ADB shell command to start a background process and get back its status in one line is failing with a syntax error
The below adb shell command returns /system/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected ';'
adb shell "tcpdump -W 3 -C 2 -i any -s 0 -w /tmp/net.pcap > /dev/null 2>&1 & ; echo x$?"

recall that a simple case like sleep 10  & , (next input line) echo $? will always show $? as 0. By contrast, try  nonesuch & followed by echo $? you will get 0, becuase the & (run in the background did what you told it) But then you get [1]+  Exit 127                nonesuch which recognizes there is no such command.


I suppose there is a man bash where it is explained that & is the last allowed char on a line. 3) You have to separate the two lines. 4) It is not helping to redirect std-err to /dev/null. You could capture that output and parse it for the error code.

